# If a promise is fine to be rejected, then how should we handle it or just not even handle it or catch it?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

If there are situations where it is fine for a promise to be rejected, due to this rejection, an error is still thrown.  How should we handle it or just ignore it?

Case 1: If the user can click a cancel button and an operation is canceled and we consider such cancelation is fine, do we just handle it by:

```
p.then(value => {
  // fulfillment handler
}, err => {});   // do nothing
```

or

```
p.then((value) => {
  // fulfillment handler
}).catch(err => {});     // do nothing
```

Or can we just totally ignore it and not use a rejection handler or catch()?

Case 2: What if we do a

```
let p = Promise.reject(1);
```

then an exception is immediately thrown.  There is no time to even catch it.  Then must we always use:

```
let p = Promise.reject(1).catch(err => {});
```

?  Actually, if `p` above is printed, it is a resolved promise, while the one without the `catch()` is a rejected promise, so I am a bit confused. I thought both should be in a rejected state.

Comment: @jfriend00 so what if user clicks cancel and in a way it is not an error... then consider it a "resolve" ?

Comment: yes, I read that always to have a catch() while learning promise... but (1) just focused too much on how it should work and not cared about error handling and (2) I thought promise rejected is just a normal thing... didn't know that an exception would be thrown

Answer (score 1):

If you use a promise rejection/exception to signal that something was cancelled, it makes sense to catch this error.

But, an important rule of thumb is that if you catch an error and you expect a certain error to be thrown (CancellationError for example), you should make sure in your catch clause that it's specifically an error of that type.

Otherwise you run the risk of some *other* exception being thrown and silently eaten up by your (empty) catch handler.

So I would usually expect this to look something like this:

```
try {
  await someOperation();
} catch (err) {
  if (!(err instanceof Cancellation)) {
    // Re-throw
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('Operation cancelled');
}
```